# User can't login with facebook login

Tags: facebook, authentication

I just started learning about facebook,I have this code, so when someone is login with their facebook account it doesn't redirect them to their account.php, it kept on reloading the page over and over again until they logout of facebook, then it stops refreshing. What can i do to fix this, I've looked everywhere online but I cant find a solution and it's really frustrating.

Thanks

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      window.location.reload();
    });
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>

<div id="wrapper">
<?php if ($user) { ?>
<div id="logobox"><?php include 'bigLogo.php';?></div>
<span class="logginginmsg">Logging in...</span><br/>
<?php
            $fb = new Facebook();
            $object = $fb->api('/me');
            $response = $fb->get('/me');
    $u = get_fbid();
    if($u == 0) {
    // The user is not found... let's create them:

        // Get the referrer if there is one
        $referrer = $_GET["ref"];
        // Check if the user was referred or not
        if (!empty($referrer)) {
            add_ref_data();
            } ?>
        <span class='heading'>Welcome!</span><br/>
        <span class='heading'>Since it's your first time here you need to        enter your Bitcoin wallet ID below.</span><br/>
        <span class='heading'>You can get one for free at <a href="https://blockchain.info/" target="_blank">BlockChain.Info</a></span><br/><br/>
        <span class='warningmsg'>Make sure you enter it correctly because it can't be changed!</span><br/>
        <form class="btcregform" action='register.php' method='post'>
            <input class="btcregforminput" type='text' value='' id='btcaddress' name='btcaddress'>
            <input class="btcregformbutton" type='submit' value='Submit' id='button' name='regButton'>
        </form>
        <div id="creditsandlinks">
            <?php include 'footerCredits.php';?>
        </div>
    <?php } else {
        // User is found! Redirect them to their account. ?>
        <script>location.href='account.php'</script>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php } else {

    // Facebook API detected no active user ID ?>
    <div id="logobox"><?php include 'bigLogo.php';?></div>
    <div id="contentbox">
        <div id="leftcontent">
            <span class="greeting">Hello guest !</span><br/>
            <p class='heading'>For your convenience VidCoin uses your existing Facebook account to authenticate you.</p>
            <p class='heading'>If it's your first time here you will be asked to provide a Bitcoin wallet ID so that we can make payments to you.</p>
            <div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true"></div><br><br>
        </div>
        <div id="rightcontent">
            <span class="rightheading">Earn Beezes</span><br/>
            <p class='heading'>Beezes is a virtual currency that can only be earned by watching short videos and do offers on our website.</p>
            <p class='heading'>You can exchange your Beezes into Bitcoins (BTC) at any time.</p>
            <p class='heading'>One VidCoin is currently worth <?php print btc_price(); ?> Satoshis.</p>
            <p class='heading'>There is no minimum amount to reach in order to exchange!</p>
        </div>  
    </div><br><br>
```

Comment: try this: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: and start with the javascript sdk first, no need to complicate things with the php sdk.